# How to shift resistance range of Linear Potentiometers by X ohms in the Positive or Negative direction?

Tags: resistors, resistance, potentiometer

For example, I have a 10k ohm (linear) Thumbwheel Potentiometer. This POT will produce values from 0 to 10k when reading its resistance.

### Positive Shift

- How do I shift resistance range values by X ohms in the
  ***positive*** direction?  E.g. a 10k POT will yield a new range of: 10 to 10,010 ohm, shifted by 10 ohms?

  [image]

*Since I am using an Arduino, I could programmatically scale the resistance value. But I do not want to do that.*

---

### Negative Shift

- How do I shift resistance value range by X ohms in the ***negative***
  direction? E.g. a 10k POT will yield a new range of: -10 to 9990 ohm,
  shifted by 10 ohms?

Comment: You mean to just **add** \$X\$ \$\Omega\$ to the resistance?

Comment: Yes, to shift the range?

Comment: @lucidgold, point is, is *X* always positive, or do you want a solution for negative *X* also?

Comment: X is currently always positive. If I want the range to be negative, how would I do that? A conductor?

Comment: You need to show how you will connect the pot. Are you connecting ground to something?

Comment: @copper.hat: Diagram updated!

Comment: How do you intend on using a resistance of -10 ohms?

Comment: Just as an aside, a pot. may have a tolerance of, say, 10%, which means the example \$10 \Omega\$ will be 'drowned' out in the noise...

Comment: As you have drawn the connections, you are not using the potentiometer as a variable resistance, but as a variable voltage. The analog input to the Arduino draws almost no current, causing almost no voltage drop on any resistor you put on the middle terminal, so it won't have any effect. Remember that the analog input reads _voltages_, not resistance. Do you want to shift the voltage by a certain amount?

Comment: Following Austin, if you just want a variable resistance the just use two terminals, and you can add the additional resistance on either side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your potentiometer going from 10k to 20k, simply hook a 10k after the potentiometer (e.g. where you get your changed Voltage).

Formula: Potentiometer range: From x to 10k+x: Add a resistor of x to the potentiometer. If you want to extend the range, then you have to use another approach.

Comment: In other words, put it in series.

Comment: @JeffBell: Got it, is my diagram correct?

Comment: @lucidgold - nope. Connect it to one end or the other. If the pot is to be used with one end tied to ground, add the resistor between the pot and ground.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Alright, so this POT has 3 pins. Using the Arduino I can read the resistance value from the middle pin. You are suggesting I connect the 10ohm resistor to GND pin (from POT)?

Comment: If you want to lift the pot's range above ground, you put a resistor between ground and the counterclockwise terminal, not on the wiper terminal.

Comment: Your diagram indicates that you are not quite asking the right question.